# Unmountable boot volume xp - halfway the loading screen

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bsod, chkdsk, hiren

Power went off. When I rebooted I started receiving `unmountable_boot_volume` on windows loading screen (that is windows started loading progress bar and all, then stopped, kept trying to read some file in the drive *audibly* failing (blip pause blip pause etc) then BSOD with `0x000000ED`). Formatted a usb stick (no cd rom drive) and added the Hiren´s Boot Cd, tried booting into "mini XP" - same blip blip bang.
What I make of it is some system file needed on boot is corrupted - the drive is not, I run chkdsk via Hiren's btw and I can also (dual) boot to linux (a horrible frustrating xandros distro I won't say more about) that's preinstalled.

My question : how can I, via hirens, locate and bypass the problematic file ? Do I need the original XP cd (I have it shipped from home but should be an older SP, I am on SP3) ?

EDIT : needless to say tried rebooting 20 + times, same behavior - the drive is *not* dying - just a particular failure. `chkdsk` reported no bad sectors btw - did not run it from command line but via a german app in Hiren's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was as simple as booting from an Arch linux live USB. I issued

```
$ mkdir /mnt/sda1
$ mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1 # IIRC
```

arch said something in the lines of "the filesystem was not unmounted correctly - repairing". Then I booted from windows which run chkdsk and that was all. So hiren's app was a no-op and 3 cheers for arch

Problem solved

Comment: Maybe Arch `mount` have something different from Ubuntu one? Same problem but mount fine without fixing.